# Can you migrate a work item type to another work item type

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

I have a situation where one team decided to create a new work item type called clarification but we do not want to migrate this new work item type instead if possible convert that to a work item type task.  Is this possible with this migration tool?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. You have to use this in the config file :

```
  "WorkItemTypeDefinition": {
    "sourceWorkItemTypeName": "targetWorkItemTypeName"
  },
```

then configure `"FieldMaps"` in the config file to convert every fields that are not identical to Tasks.